# How do I send data to a remote SSh server?

Tags: ssh

Let's say I have an ssh server running on a remote machine. SSH servers must run on port 22, so that's the only information that I have.

I need to send data to this server. I know I can use `scp` to copy a file, but what if I want to sent a buffer? Or an encoded string?

I've had success with `cat`ting a string over ssh like this:

```
cat text.txt | ssh user@host "cat > remote"
```

But this seems like a hack. Isn't there a way to send a "request" to an ssh server the way you would with an HTTP server? My understanding is that SSH servers use tcp as their base transport layer so my gut tells me that this should be possible. I just don't know where to start experimenting with this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use ssh port forwarding if you want to use tcp.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your "hack" is a hack at all. The effect is quite well-defined indeed and there's very little that could go wrong. The only thing I can think of is that if "`remote`" is an arbitrary string, then you'd have to quote it properly (but in fact, `scp` has the same problem). If that is in fact a problem for you, then you could do something like this:

```
echo "/tmp/weird file name" | cat - text.txt | ssh user@host 'read filename; cat >"$filename"'
```

Other than that, I don't see any reason to shy away from your "hack". You ask whether you can send "requests" to SSH servers, and I would argue that specifying shell commands like you've done is exactly how SSH does that.